# who makes these lights at Ikea cafeterias which don't seem be in Ikea catalog?

Tags: light-fixture

At many Ikea restaurant and Cafeterias you can see these massive and cool lights, but it doesn't seem to be something in their catalog and no other information seems available.

Even if they are custom lights, they must be made by some company given the number of them out there.

I haven't been able to find anything like it on the web.  Any information on who makes them or where to find large fixtures like these would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Pendant/Fabric Lights at Ikea resutants]

Comment: Found this.  A picture of similar looking(size wise) shades.   Came up in a google search for custom shades, just going by the picture they showed.  Do not know anything about them.  https://www.fenchelshades.com/

Answer (score 5):

Commercial lighting is a world apart from residential. Not necessarily incompatible (all has to get to the same 120V or 240V, except for some *really big* lights in stadiums, etc.) but not the kind of stuff you'll see in an ordinary retail store/web site.

In the case of IKEA (similar for any large chain), it is quite possible that they used standard fixtures, specified based on size, power and amount/color of light, but had custom shades manufactured to their specs and you won't find anything quite the same *anywhere*. IKEA has hundreds of stores worldwide. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKEA) 51 stores currently in the US. If they order 10 lights of the same type x 50 stores, that's 500 lights - enough to get a custom run without it costing too much extra per light.

This reminds me of Home Depot bathrooms - the ones I've visited are very well done, and I am really a little surprised they don't have tags on the faucets, counters, tile, etc. "Find me on aisle 17, bay 4", etc.

Comment: 277V is pretty common as well, without getting "huge" - just a common voltage where there's 480V 3-phase service, which most large commercial buildings will have.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - also 208V. The point being that the voltage (one you get past the basement electrical room) in anything from a townhouse to a single family home to an apartment building to a high-rise office building or big box store is pretty much the same. But the actual fixtures used vary widely.

Comment: You'll be surprised at just how difficult it is to use your own merchandize in your own stores. Conceptually it doesn't sound like much, but the accountants will absolutely hate you for that. The weird stuff you need to properly consume the merchandize internally without allowing people to basically just steal all your stuff... it's most likely a huge logistical nightmare due to auditing.

Comment: And using the same lampshade **worldwide** *is exactly the sort of thing IKEA would do!* And they certainly have the distribution infrastructure to move furniture around the world.  @Nelson you don't use your own merchandise. You have your design team design one specifically for internal use. So now you have a KLAATU lamp that does not go in the catalog, where all the production belongs to the facilities department.  *Not to discourage OP; I'm blindly speculating, it's possible they do no such thing... likely that lamp or even better items can be had from a lighting supply house*.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Actually, their large Hektar lamps are all over their stores installed for illumination.  Which is why I asked if someone knows the sourcing.   Thank you for your input and answer knowing that the question will be closed.  I appreciate it.